# Are there any risks to giving someone your wallet address?

Tags: fraud, donation

I set up a fundraiser for my friend and I got a message from a stranger asking for a wallet address so they can donate using BitCoin. I don’t know a whole lot about BitCoin beyond the basics, so I wanted to ask if this person does happen to be a scammer, are there are any potential risks in giving this person a BitCoin wallet address to send the donation to?

I know if he tries to send me any links or files or anything I won’t click it, I know that much, so I wouldn’t do anything more than give the address to an empty wallet. I just don’t know much about BitCoin scammers and if they have any methods other than the obvious to screw me over somehow.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you make sure you give them a new Bitcoin address (not one you're used in the past) there are no risks in just giving them an address.

If you give them an address you're used before, they may be able to see some of your old payment history.

A scammer could try to convince you they've paid you when in reality they haven't. To avoid that, give them the new address, check for the payment on your own wallet or a trusted blockchain explorer, and don't click links they give you to "prove" they've sent the money or believe that they've sent you money until you see the coins on your own wallet or blockchain explorer yourself.